# RDLC gráficos, no me muestra todas las etiquetas del eje horizontal

Tags: rdlc

Tengo un reporte con un gráfico, este muestra consumos de 1 año, el eje horizontal debe mostrar todos los meses, pero cuando se muestra el gráfico solo aparecen la etiqueta cada 2 meses como se puede notar en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que se muestren todas las etiquetas Mar-22, Abr-22, May-22.... Hasta Ene-23

He revisado la configuración pero no me muestra alguna opcion de agrupamiento, no se por que solo muestra la etiqueta cada 2 meses.

Si alguno de ustedes me podría ayudar.

Gracias.